# I'm getting a Compiler Warning Message that I don't understand?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

Please help. I typed the following code, and I am getting a Compiler Warning message C4430:

> missing type specifier - int assumed

Can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    int age = 15;

    cout << age << endl;

    if (age >= 16)
    {
        cout << "You can drive" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You cannot drive yet!" << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= age; i++)
    {
        cout << "Happy Birthday " << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I went step-by-step and retraced my code, but I am unable to find the error.

Comment: You did not declare `int main()`, but only `main()`

Comment: Thanks for the help I forgot the int main() How stupid I am.  Lol.

Comment: *"missing type specifier - int assumed"* -- usually an error message is longer than this. There is usually also an indication of **where** the error occurs, often a line number plus character position, sometimes a more visual indicator. This would answer the question of *which* symbol lacks a type specifier and is assumed to be `int`.

Comment: Voted to reopen. There is no indication that the omission of `int` was a typo; it could just as likely be a misunderstanding of C++ syntax.

Comment: @PeteBecker 
Reference: §6.9.3.1 http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main

Answer (score 1):

Your `main()` function has no return type.According to the C++ standard, it must have a return value with `int` type.

Reference: [§6.9.3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main)